# Avoid NTLM Authorization Handshake On Every Request to the REST API?

Tags: 2010, rest

I am accessing SharePoint 2010 REST API with a `System.Net.Http.HttpClient`. The server is set up with NTLM authentication, and I am accessing it over the Internet. Every time I send a request from my code, the service goes through NTLM authentication handshake, causing two 401s before showing the data. Here are two requests from my code:

[image: Subsequent requests from my code]

When I do the same thing with the browser, only the first request goes through 401 handshake, with following requests getting an immediate 200 response:

[image: browser requests do not require authentication]

Subsequent requests from the browser do not contain the `Authorization` header, and other than a few informative headers, are identical to what my code is sending:

```
GET /_vti_bin/ListData.svc/SharedDocuments HTTP/1.1
Host: contoso.com
Accept: */*
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.84 Safari/537.36
Cookie: WSS_KeepSessionAuthenticated={40c2b58d-f21f-4254-aec4-97a798dd17b5}
```

The server replies with 200 OK to the above request, though not always. After a while, it again requires the authentication handshake, and then again subsequent requests are served immediately without further authentication. I've tried this with Chrome on a Mac and with IE11 on Windows 7, and the behavior is the same.

My code sends the same `WSS_KeepSessionAuthenticated` cookie as the browser:

```
GET /_vti_bin/ListData.svc/SharedDocuments HTTP/1.1
Connection: keep-alive
Host: contoso.com
Cookie: WSS_KeepSessionAuthenticated={40c2b58d-f21f-4254-aec4-97a798dd17b5}
```

The server is always sending back the NTLM challenge to all my requests, forcing the handshake, even when two requests are sent from the same instance of `HttpClient`.

Here is the code I am using to contact the server:

```
let baseUri url = 
    let u = Uri url
    UriBuilder(u.Scheme, u.Host).Uri

let ntlmCred username password baseUri = 
    let cc = System.Net.CredentialCache()
    cc.Add(baseUri, "ntlm", NetworkCredential(username, (password:string)))
    cc

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =
    let username = argv.[0]
    let password = argv.[1] 
    let url = argv.[2]
    let baseAddr = baseUri url

    use w = new WebRequestHandler()
    w.PreAuthenticate <- true
    w.Credentials <- ntlmCred username password baseAddr
    w.UnsafeAuthenticatedConnectionSharing <- true

    w.CookieContainer.Add(new Cookie("WSS_KeepSessionAuthenticated", "{40c2b58d-f21f-4254-aec4-97a798dd17b5}", "/", baseAddr.Authority))

    use client = new HttpClient(w) 
    let r = client.GetAsync(url).Result
    // This second request from the same instance still causes the NTLM authorization handshake
    client.GetAsync(url).Result |> ignore
    r |> printfn "%A"
    0
```

My understanding was that providing a valid `WSS_KeepSessionAuthenticated` cookie should side-step the constant authorization on every request, but it does not seem to be the case, even though the cookie is required for rest calls (otherwise the server bombs with a 400 bad request).

Is there a way to avoid authentication handshake on every single call?

Comment: Great question!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're using C# but, FWIW, if you can use Java, I've found the Apache HttpClient (4.3.5) support for NTLM to be fantastic and I only see new challenges after the client context has be inactive for quite a while.

**Edit**
BTW, here's one trick you might use if the challenge continues to happen on every REST call and you can't find a better library. As I've observed the challenge\response dance of NTLM, I've seen that it sends the entire request body back and forth each time (it appears to be 3 times based on my traces). So, any time you're going to be making a large payload call such as a large file upload, issue a small payload GET first. In my work, I've done this with a GET on the web root with `?$select=ServerRelativeUrl`. I do this because, as I said, if my connection has gone unused for some period of time, the challenge may occur again under the covers. So, if I issue a small payload GET first, the negotiation can happen back and forth with a small payload.

Comment: That's interesting. Will try using another .NET HTTP client library to see if that improves things. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks man, this is a great tip. Appreciate you for following up.